# Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, Dropout, Activation, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

# fraction of the input to drop; helps prevent overfitting
dropout = 0.2
window_size = 10

# build a 3-layer LSTM RNN
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(
    LSTM(window_size, return_sequences=True, 
         input_shape=(window_size, x_train.shape[-1]))
)

model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout))
# Bidirectional allows for training of sequence data forwards and backwards
model.add(
    Bidirectional(LSTM((window_size * 2), return_sequences=True)
)) 

model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout))
model.add(
    Bidirectional(LSTM(window_size, return_sequences=False))
) 

model.add(Dense(units=1))
# linear activation function: activation is proportional to the input
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Give a summary
model.summary()

#Model train
batch_size=58

model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam'
)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10, verbose=1 ,validation_split=0.2)
```

I am getting the error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 1)

How do I solve this problem? Thank you!